# How to add string at the bottom of a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, string, button, scrollview

I would like to know how to add new strings at the bottom of a `ScrollView` every time I press a button.

For example at the beginning there is `sentence1`, press button, then `sentence2` is under `sentence1`, press button, `sentence3` is under `sentence2`, etc

I know how to make a scrollView and I have an array of strings to display:

```
final int[] sentences = new int[]{
        R.String.sentence1, 
        R.String.sentence1, 
        R.String.sentence2, 
        R.String.sentence3, 
        R.String.sentence4
};
```

And I know how to make them appear one after another when a button is pressed (kind off replacing the previous one, like a `TextSwitch` but without the animation) :

```
if(nextSentenceId < sentences.length) {
   officeOBSDialog.setText(sentences[nextSentenceId]);
   ++nextSentenceId;
}
```

Do you have any idea how I could manage to do that or what could I use? It occured to me that I could use like a layout inflator but I don't know how to put that to practice and where to put it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView

However, if you consistently want to use `ScrollView` cause your screen UI is simple. You can simply wrap a LinearLayout with vertical orientation by a ScrollView.

> activity.xml

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- your button declaration -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In your activity java file, add new row programmatically by:

```
private int position=0;
final int[] sentences = new int[]{
    R.String.sentence1, 
    R.String.sentence1, 
    R.String.sentence2, 
    R.String.sentence3, 
    R.String.sentence4
};

//inside onCreate() method
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View view){
         TextView textView = new TextView(YourActivityClass.this);
         textView.setText(sentences[position++]);
         ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnContainer)).addView(textView);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me ! I have a little problem with your java code, the new TextView(this); cannot be applied, I can't pass multiple string in setText() and I cannot resolve method addView.

Comment: @Emma.bk i have editted my answer, check it out and told me if you still get stuck with my answer

Comment: @Emma.bk can you give me a upvote to encourage me! Thank you!

Comment: I sure did, but since I have only 13 of reputation it's recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score ! Thanks again !

Comment: Ok, no problem! I am currently having 956 reputations and trying to to reach 1000. I will try my best to reach it!